# Convert optional string to double in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a option string and want to convert  that to double.
this worked in Swift 2 , but since converted to Swift 3, I am getting value of 0.

```
var dLati = 0.0
dLati = (latitude as NSString).doubleValue
```

I have check and latitude has a optional string value of something like -80.234543218675654 , but dLati value is 0
*************** ok, new update for clarity *****************
I have a viewcontroller which i have a button in it, and when the button is touched, it will call another viewcontroller and pass a few values to it
here is the code for the first viewcontroller

```
var currentLatitude: String? = ""
var currentLongitude: String? = ""
var deviceName = ""
var address = ""
// somewhere in the code, currentLatitude and currentLongitude are get set  
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "map" {
       let destViewController : MapViewController = segue.destination as! MapViewController
       print(currentLongitude!)  // Print display: Optional(-80.192279355363768)
       print(currentLatitude!) // Print display: Optional(25.55692663937162) 
       destViewController.longitude = currentLongitude!
       destViewController.latitude = currentLatitude!
       destViewController.deviceName = deviceName
       destViewController.address = address
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the second view controller called MapViewController

```
   var longitude: String? = " "
   var latitude: String? = ""
   .
   .
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       if let lat = latitude {
          print(lat) // Print display: optiona(25.55692663937162)
          dLati = (lat as NSString).doubleValue
          print(dLati)  // Print display: 0.0
       }
       .
       .
   }
```

Thanks
Borna

Comment: What does `latitude` come from? How is it declared? Is it guaranteed to always have a non-nil, valid number value?

Answer (score 27):

A safe way to achieve this without needing to use Foundation types is using Double's initializer:

```
if let lat = latitude, let doubleLat = Double(lat) {
  print(doubleLat)  // doubleLat is of type Double now
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Unwrap the `latitude` value safely and then use

```
var dLati = 0.0

if let lat = latitude {
    dLati = (lat as NSString).doubleValue
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
let dLati = Double(latitude ?? "") ?? 0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works fine.

```
var dLati = 0.0
let latitude: String? = "-80.234543218675654"
if let strLat = latitude {
    dLati = Double(strLat)!
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Just because the OP's `latitude` value happens to have this particular value in one case doesn't mean it will always have a valid value. Proper unwrapping should be done.

Comment: Still didn't work. In the debugger if I print the description of latitude, I get this--> Printing description of self.latitude:
"Optional(26.55692667237162)" .And the value of dLati --> Printing description of self.dLati:
0.0

Comment: @borna You have to unwrap the value of latitude first. Check my answer. Also provide some source where are you getting latitude value and in which type

Comment: Rajan, Still doesn't work. this is what I have 
var longitude: String? = " "
 var latitude: String? = " "         
if let lat = latitude {
           print(lat)
           dLati = (lat as NSString).doubleValue
           print(dLati)
}

Results of print statements
Optional(26.55692667237162)
0.0

so, why dLati is still 0.0?

Comment: @borna how can print result to `Optional(26.55692667237162)` . You havent set that anywhere in your code. As per your code u just setup an empty string and nothing else. Then where this value came from. `dLati` is 0.0 because you have empty string in lat long

Comment: @Rajan I added more code to my original question to make the issues I am having more understandable

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply in one line.

```
var latitude: Double = Double("-80.234543218675654") ?? 0.0
```

This creates a variable named latitude that is of type Double that is either instantiated with a successful Double from String or is given a fallback value of 0.0

Answer (score 2):

When you get a string with double value something like this

```
"Optional(12.34567)"
```

You can use a Regex which takes out the double value from the string.
This is the example code for a Regex if the string is `"Optional(12.34567)"`:

```
let doubleLatitude = location.latitude?.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^\\.\\d+]", with: "", options: [.regularExpression])
```

Answer (score 0):

Don´t convert it to an `NSString`, you can force it to a `Double` but have a fallback if it fails. Something like this:

```
let aLat: String? = "11.123456"
let bLat: String? = "11"
let cLat: String? = nil

let a = Double(aLat!) ?? 0.0 // 11.123456
let b = Double(bLat!) ?? 0.0 // 11
let c = Double(cLat!) ?? 0.0 // 0
```

So in your case:

```
dLati = Double(latitude!) ?? 0.0
```

**Update:**
To handle `nil` values do the following (note that let cLat is `nil`:

```
// Will succeed
if let a = aLat, let aD = Double(aLat!) {
    print(aD)
}
else {
    print("failed")
}

// Will succeed
if let b = bLat, let bD = Double(bLat!) {
    print(bD)
}
else {
    print("failed")
}

// Will fail
if let c = cLat, let cD = Double(cLat!) {
    print(cD)
}
else {
    print("failed")
}
```

Comment: Man, it will crash if any of the values `aLat`,`bLat` or `cLat` is nil

Comment: let dLatitude = Double(latitude ?? "") ?? 0.0

Comment: Actually optional was part of the string. Not sure how optional got added in the string? The way I fixed it was like this. latitude was  this string "Optional(26.33691567239162)" then I did this ---> let start = latitude.index(latitude.startIndex, offsetBy: 9)      
        let end = latitude.index(latitude.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)      
        let range = start..<end      
        latitude = latitude.substring(with: range)      
   and final value was this   -->  26.33691567239162

Comment: @borna, the reason it had Optional is because it´s an option and you need to make the that the value has a value. I would not recommend the way you have done it because if the value is `nil` and you´re trying to make it the way you have solved it it will crash with the error **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. Checkout my answer and see if you can update your code to be more safe.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the word optional was part of the string. Not sure how it got added in the string? But the way I fixed it was like this. latitude was this string "Optional(26.33691567239162)" then I did this code

```
let start = latitude.index(latitude.startIndex, offsetBy: 9) 
let end = latitude.index(latitude.endIndex, offsetBy: -1) 
let range = start..<end 
latitude = latitude.substring(with: range)
```

and got this as the final value
26.33691567239162

Answer (score 0):

In **swift 3.1**, we can combine extensions and Concrete Constrained Extensions

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String
{
    var asDouble: Double
    {
        return NSString(string: self ?? "").doubleValue
    }
}
```

Or

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String
{
        var asDouble: Double
        {
            return Double(str ?? "0.00") ?? 0.0
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4

```
 let YourStringValue1st = "33.733322342342" //The value is now in string
 let YourStringValue2nd = "73.449384384334" //The value is now in string

 //MARK:- For Testing two Parameters 
 if let templatitude = (YourStringValue1st as? String), let templongitude = (YourStringValue2nd as? String)
 {
     movetosaidlocation(latitude: Double(templat)!, longitude: Double(templong)!, vformap: cell.vformap)
 }


 let YourStringValue = "33.733322342342" //The value is now in string
 //MARK:- For Testing One Value
 if let tempLat = (YourStringValue as? String)
 {
      let doublevlue = Double(tempLat)
      //The Value is now in double (doublevlue)
 }
```