# Convert value of type 'String?' to type 'NSString'

Tags: swift

I was following the instructions on a book [1] for Swift 1.2 on how to make a simple temperature conversion application using one text field, one button and one label for the result. I'm using Swift 3. You type the temperature in the text field, push the "Convert" button and you should get the result, but I get "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to type 'NSString' in coercion".

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tempText : UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func convertTemp( _ sender: Any ) {

        let fahrenheit      = ( tempText.text as NSString ).doubleValue
        let celsius         = ( fahrenheit - 32 ) / 1.8
        let resultText      = "Celsius \(celsius)"
        resultLabel.text    = resultText
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I can add an exclamation mark after as like this:

```
    let fahrenheit      = ( tempText.text as! NSString ).doubleValue
```

But I still get a warning: "Cast from 'String?' to unrelated type 'NSString' always fails".

How should this be done in Swift 3?

[1] Neil Smyth. 2015. iOS 8 App Development Essentials - Second Edition: Learn to Develop iOS 8 Apps using Xcode and Swift 1.2. ISBN 978-1511713337.

Comment: Following a book on Swift 1.2 is going to cause you far more problems than it is worth. Swift 4 will be out in a few weeks (beta right now). Do yourself a huge favor and find tutorials written for Swift 3.

Comment: Why would anyone try to use a book for Swift 1.2 when programming Swift 3? These are totally different languages!

Comment: `let fahrenheit  = Double(tempText.text)`? See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372656/convert-optional-string-to-double-in-swift-3

Comment: You should really find a book on Swift 3, or maybe even Swift 4 (those'll be readily available soon enough)

Comment: You can do `Double(tempText.text!)!`. Or, safer `guard let string = tempText.text, let fahrenheit = Double(string) else { return }`.

Comment: @Larme Your advice seems to work. Now I have the below two lines and no errors or warnings: Line: let fahrenheit = Double( tempText.text! ). Line: let celsius = ( fahrenheit! - 32 ) / 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

A type cast to `NSString` to get a `Double` is a pretty bad habit (even in Swift 1).

A safe Swift 3 solution is to optional bind the `text` property and the `Double` conversion

```
@IBAction func convertTemp(_ sender: Any ) {

    if let degrees = tempText.text, let fahrenheit = Double(degrees) {
        let celsius         = ( fahrenheit - 32 ) / 1.8
        let resultText      = "Celsius \(celsius)"
        resultLabel.text    = resultText
    } else {
        resultLabel.text    = "Conversion failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: @tomihasa Please note that this answer is much better than the two lines you mentioned in your last comment below the question. This code won't crash when the user enters a value that isn't a valid number.